# Variable Declarations in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a shell script that reads from a fil

```
file="a.txt"
while read line
do

line1 = $(awk '{if($1 == "Only")print"$3;"}' "$line")
echo "$line1"
line1 = $(sed '$s/.$//' "$line1")
line2 = $(awk '{if($1 == "Only")print"$4";}' "$line")
line3 = $(sed -r 's/^.{3}//' "$line1line2")
done  <"$file"
```

I keep getting this error `a.sh: 5: a.sh: line1: not found`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No space allowed before and after the assignment operator. Change your code to:

```
line1=$(awk '{if($1 == "Only")print"$3;"}' "$line")
echo "$line1"
line1=$(sed '$s/.$//' "$line1")
line2=$(awk '{if($1 == "Only")print"$4";}' "$line")
line3=$(sed -r 's/^.{3}//' "$line1line2")
```

See [Variable Assignment](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) for more details.

Comment: Cool, got it. Damn bash :P